# Using Google Cloud ecosystem vs building your own microservice architecture

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, microservices, google-cloud-dataflow

Building in the Google Cloud ecosystem is really powerful. I really like how you can ingest files to Cloud Storage then Data Flow enriches, transforms and aggregates the data, and then finally stored in BigQuery or Cloud SQL.

I have a couple of questions to help me have a better understanding. 
If you are to build a big data product using the Google services.

1. When a front-end web application (might be built in React) submits a file to Cloud storage it may take some time before it completely processes. The client might want to view the status the file in the pipeline. They then might want to do something with the result on completion. How are front-end clients expected know when a file has completed processed and ready? Do they need to poll data from somewhere?
2. If you currently have a microservice architecture in which each service does a different kind of processing. For example one might parse a file, another might processes messages. The services communicate using Kafka or RabbitMQ and store data in Postgres or S3. 
   If you adopt the Google services ecosystem could you replace that microservice architecture with Cloud storage, dataflow, Cloud SQL/Store?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) (topic subscription/publication service).

> Cloud Pub/Sub brings the scalability, flexibility, and reliability of enterprise message-oriented middleware to the cloud. By providing many-to-many, asynchronous messaging that decouples senders and receivers, it allows for secure and highly available communication between independently written applications.

I believe Pub/Sub can mostly substitute Kafka or RabitMQ in your case.

> How are front-end clients expected know when a file has completed      processed and ready? Do they need to poll data from somewhere?

For example, if you are using dataflow API to process the file, Cloud dataflow can publish the progress and send the status to a **topic**. Your front end (app engine) just needs to subscribe to that **topic** and receive update.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1)
Dataflow does not offer inspection to intermediary results. If a frontend wants more progress about an element being processed in a Dataflow pipeline, custom progress reporting will need to be built into the Pipline.

One idea, is to write progress updates to a sink table and output molecules to that at various parts of the pipeline. I.e. have a BigQuery sink where you write rows like ["element_idX", "PHASE-1 DONE"]. Then a frontend can query for those results. (I would avoid overwriting old rows personally, but many approaches can work).

You cand do this by consuming the PCollection in both the new sink, and your pipeline's next step.

2)
Is your Microservice architecture using a "Pipes and filters" pipeline style approach? I.e. each service reads from a source (Kafka/RabbitMQ) and writes data out, then the next consumes it?

Probably the best way to do setup one a few different Dataflow pipelines, and output their results using a Pub/Sub or Kafka sink, and have the next pipeline consume that Pub/Sub sink. You may also wish to sink them to a another location like BigQuery/GCS, so that you can query out these results again if you need to.

There is also an option to use Cloud Functions instead of Dataflow, which have [Pub/Sub and GCS triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/). A microservice system can be setup with several Cloud Functions.